# Android Studio logcat only shows Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, debugging, adb, logcat

It started happening a few days ago and I already tried many solutions but nothing helped. What I tried:

- Invalidate cache / restart
- Restart logcat
- Revoke USB debugging authorizations
- Selecting "No filters"
- Reinstall app
- Switch log level between verbose, error and debug
- increase log buffer size from developer options

Logcat (log level: verbose | only selected application):

```
2020-11-29 20:03:05.165 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
2020-11-29 20:03:05.168 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug, 1:615339790521:android:a54ce30e1047dc49fdcb68
2020-11-29 20:03:05.169 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 33025
2020-11-29 20:03:05.169 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-11-29 20:03:05.170 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug
2020-11-29 20:03:05.170 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-11-29 20:03:05.218 18576-18608/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-11-29 20:03:05.255 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-11-29 20:03:05.286 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:03:05.300 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:03:05.635 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-11-29 20:03:05.672 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:03:05.969 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1034755035
2020-11-29 20:03:06.027 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:03:06.030 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:03:06.710 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-11-29 20:03:06.711 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 6
2020-11-29 20:03:11.837 18576-18615/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-11-29 20:05:02.316 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 116300
2020-11-29 20:05:02.329 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-11-29 20:05:02.579 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1034871354
2020-11-29 20:05:02.696 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-29 20:05:02.700 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-11-29 20:05:02.702 18576-18681/com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
```

Log from 'Run' tab

```
11/29 20:50:59: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug/com.tashila.mywalletfree.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 23766 on device 'xiaomi-redmi_note_8-142ae1cf'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug, 1:615339790521:android:a54ce30e1047dc49fdcb68
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 33025
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.tashila.mywalletfree.debug
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1037630815
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 6
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 72971
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1037703790
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
```

What should I do to fix this? I've been struggling to fix this for days. Please help

Comment: if you run the app and select the "Run" tab on the bottom it shows the correct log?
the default setting for logcat is "Show only selected application", that show only the firebase log too?

Comment: @simoneviozzi Yeah, only firebase log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody faces this problem again, I had the same problem and also tried everything listed above (which didn't help). In such a case, this appears to be a problem not of Android Studio or Logcat, but the device itself (you can verify this by connecting a different device/emulator, logs should show up fine). What fixed this for me was updating the OS of the device (resetting might also help).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by configuring the Registry Buffer Size in the Developer Options. It was deactivated while I had the error. Set it to 1mb and the logcat started to work normally again.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything listed above and many other answers but it didn't help. It only helps after the `off-debugging` option and `on` again.